# How to Manage Item Attributes and Use Methods from DB | Object Orient Item System

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, object

i got my items, inventories and inventory owners in a DB.

I got an Table named "items" where i store all infos about the item.
I got another Table named "inventory_item_assignment" where i save the assigned item to what inventory and how much items from same type in there.
I got another table named "inventorys" where all Data about the Inventory is stored.

Basically i wanna create an Inventory System.
Now i got my Question here:
I want to implement an Item Usage Client Side, so i get all the Data from the DB Server Side and send it to the client.
But how do i handle the Item Usage in a good way?
I dont want to have like one use Method and 2000x switch case in there.

I thought about an item interface with the attributes and methods.
Create for every item a class that implements the interface and make my things there.

But how do i create the right Item Object from my DB? Like i cant go with name or sth because i have items that have spacebars inside.

Base purpose of that is i wanna have all to one item at one place and not crazy everywhere.

My current inteface:

```
export interface item {
    id: number
    name: string;
    weight: number;
    sigleUse: boolean;

    use(): void;
}
```

Test Item:

```
import { item } from "../../../interfaces/item";

class HamburgerItem implements item {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    weight: number;
    sigleUse: boolean;
    use(): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    
}
```

Happy about answers.

Greets

I tryed one Item Object but that would be a huge switch case statement